# What was the name of the man who was beaten by a crowd for tearing up a war poster during WWI?

Tags: world-war-one

I remember learning in high school about an incident occurring (I think) in America during World War I in which a foreign man (I remember as Turkish) who did not read English, having seen a war poster featuring the Kaiser and thinking it was pro-German, tore up the poster and was subsequently captured and beaten by a crowd of people who mistook his actions as those of an enemy agent. However, I can't remember his name and I can't seem to locate him on Google. Did this actually happen, and if so, what was the name of the individual?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If he was Turkish his country was on the axis side.

Comment: I know which side of the war Turkey was on. Obviously he thought he was being pro-American, but whether I'm remembering his nationality correctly is another question. The immigrant status of the man is mostly just relevant to the fact that he couldn't read the English on the poster.

Comment: @NeMo except that the axis was in wwii. central powers were in wwi against the entente.

Comment: Fair enough, in ww1 they didn't call it the axis. Was just pointing out the story doesn't make sense if he's Turkish.